# Rewrite router - not controller action

Tags: checkout, overrides

I would like to rewrite checkout router and have my own controller.

like this `mysite.com/checkout/mycontroller/myaction`

How can this be possible in magento.

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <My_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">My_Checkout_Checkout</My_Checkout>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

Which does not work.

What is configuration for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<My_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">My_Checkout_Checkout</My_Checkout>
```

should be

```
<My_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">My_Checkout</My_Checkout>
```

and your controller should go into `My/Checkout/controllers/` folder.

Comment: i had that previousl which did not work .  Should the folder structure for module then be app/code/local/My/Checkout/controllers/MyController.php or app/code/local/My/Checkout/controllers/Checkout/MyController.php

Comment: `app/code/local/My/Checkout/controllers/MyController.php`